# How to add Image in React? Image won't show on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, tailwind-css

I am trying to add an image within React. But my image won't load.

This is the div I created for the image:

```
<div>
<Image src={devsimone} />
</div>
```

My imports:

```
import { BsFillMoonStarsFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { AiFillLinkedin, AiFillGithub, AiOutlineMail } from "react-icons/ai";
import Image from "next/image";
import devsimone from "../public/public/portphoto.png";
```

Here is where my image is located in my directory:

[Image in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoVIY.png)

Steps I've tried:

- removing the image and adding it back
- directly copying and pasting the images path from the directory.
- moving the image around within the directory.

Comment: A [glance at the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image) shows that your `Image` component is missing 3 mandatory props.

Answer (score 0):

As React knows its Public directory, you can add the image to the component by defining the image path only.

```
<img src="/portphoto.png" alt="image" />
```

Here "/" indicates the Public folder.